# Search for XML elements using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, xpath

I have the following XML file :

```
<warehouse>
  <cat id="computer">
    <item>
      <SN>1</SN>
      <name>Toshiba</name>
      <quantity>12</quantity>
      <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 3 GB HD: 512 GB</description>
      <price>400 USD</price>
    </item>
    <item>
      <SN>22</SN>
      <name>Toshiba</name>
      <quantity>12</quantity>
      <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 3 GB HD: 512 GB</description>
      <price>400 USD</price>
    </item>
  </cat>
  <cat id="Stationery">
    <item>
      <SN> 33 </SN>
      <name>note books</name>
      <quantity>250</quantity>
      <description>Caterpiller</description>
      <price>5 USD</price>
    </item>
  </cat>
  <cat id="Furniture">
    <item>
      <SN> 1 </SN>
      <name>dasd</name>
      <quantity>asdasd</quantity>
      <description>das</description>
      <price>dasd</price>
    </item>
    <item>
      <SN>44</SN>
      <name>Toshiba</name>
      <quantity>12</quantity>
      <description>CPU: CORE I5 RAM: 3 GB HD: 512 GB</description>
      <price>400 USD</price>
    </item>
  </cat>
</warehouse>
```

and i have the following web form page for generate queries :(i need reputation to insert image so i'll try to descrip it)

```
choose where to search : (dropdownlist)
insert sn : (textbox)
generate query: (button)
[labels]
```

I want to return `(name,description,price,quantity)` for `SN==Textbox.text where <cat id= dropdownlist.text>` in the label. can u help using LINQ or XPATH or any other methods.

I have tried this code , but i dont know to insert the `SN==Textbox.text where <cat id= dropdownlist.text>` condition into it !! please help me.

```
 XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("/XML/Cat1.xml"));
    var persons = from person in xmlDoc.Descendants("item")

    select new
    {
    SN = person.Element("SN").Value,
    name = person.Element("name").Value,
    quantity = person.Element("quantity").Value,
    description = person.Element("description").Value,
    price = person.Element("price").Value,
    };

    foreach (var person in persons)
{
label1.Text = person.SN "<br />";
label2.Text = person.name"<br />";
label3.Text = person.description"<br />";
label4.Text = person.price"<br />";
label5.Text = person.quantity"<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest doing when you want to apply a dynamic filter to a data source is:

1. Select the stuff you're going to filter.
2. Filter it as needed.
3. Select values from the filtered stuff.
4. Repeat from step 2 as needed.

So you should have something like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dropdownlist.text) &&
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.text))
{
    // ERROR - must specify filter criteria
}

// select all cats
IEnumerable<XElement> cats = xmlDoc.Descendants("cat");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dropdownlist.text))
{
    // filter by category
    cats = cats.Where(c => (string)c.Attribute("id") == dropdownlist.text);
}

// select all items in the selected cats
IEnumerable<XElement> items = cats.SelectMany(c => c.Descendants("item"));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.text))
{
    // filter items by SN
    items = items.Where(i => ((string)i.Element("SN")).Trim() == textbox.text);
}

var persons = from person in items
              select new
              {
                  SN = (string)person.Element("SN"),
                  name = (string)person.Element("name"),
                  quantity = (string)person.Element("quantity"),
                  description = (string)person.Element("description"),
                  price = (string)person.Element("price"),
              };

// use persons as needed
```

Here is how you could do this all at once with the query comprehension syntax:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dropdownlist.text) &&
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.text))
{
    // ERROR - must specify filter criteria
}

var persons = from cat in xmlDoc.Descendants("cat")
              where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dropdownlist.text) || 
                     (string)cat.Attribute("id") == dropdownlist.text)
              from person in cat.Descendants("item")
              where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.text) ||
                     ((string)person.Element("SN")) == textbox.text)
              select new
              {
                  SN = (string)person.Element("SN"),
                  name = (string)person.Element("name"),
                  quantity = (string)person.Element("quantity"),
                  description = (string)person.Element("description"),
                  price = (string)person.Element("price"),
              };
```

Comment: can u please edit my code for somrthing like .
var persons = from person in xmlDoc.Descendants("cat") where id == dropdownlist.text && sn==textbox xml.doc(item)

sorry for bad description and syntax but i really need to edit it like that , if u know what i mean ??

Comment: and your code is given me problem with IEnumerable : cant be used with type argument

Comment: @RefaatKh I don't understand why you "need" it to be in query comprehension syntax, but please see my edit. I think I have also fixed the error you were seeing.

Comment: It works, thx alot.
i re fixed the errors